# Parallels Plesk Panel connecting to database server connection string

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, plesk

I am using Entity Framework to access the data from my database. It's an MVC application and works fine locally. When I deploy the application on hosting (Parallels Plesk Panel, MS hosting) I get problems with accessing the SQL server instance. There are options in the cPanel which hold connection strings. 
LocalSqlServer:

> data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
>   `xContainer:`metadata=res://*/Models.x.csdl|res://*/Models.x.ssdl|res://*/Models.x.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=

When I upload the site xContainer is generated alone. I found the sql server's instance name and applied it to the data source. In my web.config file I am using the the xContainer. The code after this paragraph is what it seems logic to me to add after the `connection string=` in the xContainer.

I have tried this with various properties. Data source, initial catalog, and the other info are filled into the conn string (here I am showing only /).

> Data Source=x;Initial Catalog=/;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=/;Password=/;MultipleActiveResultSets=True providerName=

The error I receive is that the sql server instance cannot be found. If I add the last piece of code to the container it tells that I don't have a `providerName`, After adding a `providerName` the string is deleted to the starting xContainer string:

> metadata=res://*/Models.x.csdl|res://*/Models.x.ssdl|res://*/Models.x.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=

Answer (score 0):

```
The error I receive is that the **sql server instance cannot be found**.
```

So, what is the SQL instance name? :)

it maybe not ".\SQLEXPRESS" but ".\SQLEXPRESS2012" or even ".\MSSQLSERVER" or anything else.

Comment: I found the name of the sql instance and applied it. I still get the same error. I think the problem is with the cpanel which generates connection string which I can't set as i would like. I got no problems with the connection string on the official microsoft azure hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Edit the `Web.Config` file manually. The ASP.NET Settings page will remove the `providerName`.

An example of a connection string using `EntityClient` is below. You can remove the metadata information if you're not using an Entity Model. You will notice the `providerName` is outside of the actual `connectionString` and is the reason you will need to edit the file manually.

`connectionString="metadata=ModelInformation;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=IP;initial catalog=DATABASE;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`